# Adjust items height to fit its RecyclerView according to screen size

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a `RecyclerView` with height:match_parent which displays 16 items vertically with fixed height in adapter. Everything works fine except when it comes to the different screen sizes. In larger screens there is a space remained at the bottom after 16 items are displayed, where on small screen phones it perfectly fits to the bottom. I am looking for a way where list items heights are adjusted to the `RecyclerView` height till the end without scrollable.

Check the Screenshots below for more clarification

**Problem:**

[image]

**Expectation:**

[image]

My approach was to make the Item weight set to 1, hence when rendering into the `RecyclerView` 16 times, they will share the same height within the `RecyclerView`. Unfortunately that didn't work for me.

My RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/rv_morning"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

My Adapter:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: change height of the layout to 0dp

Comment: If you're doing this keep in mind no views would be recycled ergo its pointless to have a recylerview.

Answer (score 2):

The exact solution for your problem is the flexible layout manager for ReyclerView.

[More about flexible layouts.](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html)

[An example illustrating the use of flexible layouts.](https://blog.devcenter.co/unboxing-the-flexboxlayout-a7cfd125f023)

Comment: Adding links is helpful but writing a few more lines about the same helps even more.

Comment: tried it, but it didn't have any effect on my recyclerView.